# C# Reflection SetValue

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I am trying to create a unit test to test a specific edge case, and I am using Reflection to get hold of a private property of a class.

Whilst I can use

```
 var getPrivateProperty = obj.GetType().GetProperty("somename", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
 getPrivateProperty.SetValue(obj, newValue, null);
```

The issue I have is that the property is set as null in the class and is then set to an instance of object in a method. In my specific test I need to set this property to an instance of an object, but I am still getting the infamous error of

> Object not set to an instance of an object". I have tried this:

```
getPrivateProperty.SetValue(obj, new List<string>() {item, item2}, null);
```

Is there a way to set the property to be an instance of an object in order to complete my test?

Comment: Figure out what's null, and don't give it a null for that.

Comment: Mark the property internal and use the [`InternalsVisibleToAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx) with your test project.

Comment: Can you post a [mcve] including the class that you are reflecting into?  It's difficult to debug reflection issues without knowing exactly what you're working with.

Comment: Just a Fyi, you should look in to using [`Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.PrivateObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.privateobject) it is a wrapper over the reflection and makes it a lot easier to use. `new PrivateOjbect(obj).SetFieldOrProperty("somename", newValue);`

Comment: Are you sure you are trying to assign a value to a property and not a field? A private property is fairly rare, but a private field is common.

Comment: Sorry I meant to say a field, and this gets set in a method, but it is not the method I am interested but something else and I would like to set this field for the particular case I am interested in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid fragile reflection consider using the [`InternalsVisibleToAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx) with your test project.

Put the attribute in a well known location in your project. Somewhere like `App_Start` in ASP.NET 4 or the project root in ASP.NET Core.

`AssemblyAttributes.cs`

```
[assembly:System.Runtime.CompilerServices.InternalsVisibleTo("SomeProject.Tests")]
```

Then mark your `private` field as `internal`.

```
public class Foo
{
    internal string Bar;

    public void MethodThatUsesBar()
    {
    }
}
```

Now the Test project can reference the `internal` field.

```
public class FooTests
{
    public void TestMethodThatUsesBar()
    {
        var foo = new Foo { Bar = "This works now" };
        foo.MethodThatUsesBar();
        // Some Assertion
    }
}
```

---

Another way is to use the [`PrivateObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.privateobject) from `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting`.

```
public class FooTests
{
    public void TestMethodThatUsesBar()
    {
        var foo = new Foo();
        var fooWrapper = new PrivateObject(foo);
        fooWrapper.SetField("Bar", "This works too.");

        foo.MethodThatUsesBar();

        // Some Assertion
    }
}
```

Comment: He is trying to set a private property, not an internal one. This is a neater solution in that case, though.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with this code:

```
public class Foo
{
    private List<string> somename { get; set; }
}
```

and then:

```
var foo = new Foo();
var fooType = foo.GetType();
var somenameProperty = fooType.GetProperty("somename", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
somenameProperty.SetValue(foo, new List<string>() { "abc", "def" }, null);
```

and it works, but, as suggested in the comments, if you change the declaration of the 'somename' property to become a field, then 'somenameProperty' will be null because you should use GetField instead of GetProperty:

```
public class Foo
{
    private List<string> somename;
}
```

and then:

```
var foo = new Foo();
var fooType = foo.GetType();
var somenameField = fooType.GetField("somename", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
somenameField.SetValue(foo, new List<string>() { "abc", "def" });
```